# Optimization similar to Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find a way to solve an Optimization problem as follows:
I have 22 different objects that can be selected more than once. I have a evaluation function `f` that takes the multiplicities and calculates the total value.

`f` is a product over fractions of linear (affine) terms and as such, differentiable and even smooth in the allowed region.

I want to optimize f with respect to the 22 variables, with the additional conditions that certain sums may not exceed certain values (for example, if a,...,v are my variables, `a + e + i + m + q + s <= 9`). By this, all of the variables are bounded.

If f were strictly monotonuous, this could be solved optimally by a (minimalistically modified) knapsack solution. However, the function isnt convex. That means it is even impossible to assume that if taking an object A is better than B on an empty knapsack, that this choice holds even when adding a third object C (as C could modify B's benefit to be better than A). This means that a greedy algorithm cannot be used;

Are there similar algorithms that solve such a problem in a optimal (or at least, nearly optimal) way?

EDIT: As requested, an example of what the problem is (I chose 5 variables a,b,c,d,e for simplicity)
for example,

```
f(a,b,c,d,e) = e*(a*0.45+b*1.2-1)/(c+d)
```

(Every variable only appears once, if this helps at all)
Also, for example, `a+b+c=4`, `d+e=3`

The problem is to optimize that with respect to a,b,c,d,e as integers. There is a bunch of optimization algorithms that hold for convex functions, but very few for non-convex...

Comment: Can you give out some examples? I cannot quite understand your question.

Comment: You need to say more about what `f` is like.  At the moment it is a black box: you could probably imagine a number of pathological examples that would dup standard techniques that assume e.g. `f` is differentiable.

Comment: @phs: oh god. yes. f is differentiable (even smooth in the allowed area). It would be best to handle it mostly "blackbox-y" however.

Comment: @songlj the function is a product of fractions of affine terms and therefore not strictly increasing. I will add an example in less variables

Comment: If you get no joy here, might be worth trying http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CBenni Not necessarily.  The more we know about it, the greater the odds it could be addressed with an algorithm that is faster, but makes more assumptions.  Would `f`, for example, be a polynomial over  your 22 variables?

Comment: @phs, no. It is no polynomial and not even a product over those. I wrote a bit over the structure of the function.

Comment: What about a stochastic optimization technique, like simulated annealing or genetic algorithms?

Comment: @mbeckish I have now decided to use a fast local search algorithm  (apparently it is a genetic algorithm, but I am not sure about that) and start it from several starting points. The optimums tend to lie near the edges of the area, therefore the algorithm tends to converge pretty well. Simulated appealing works best if there are several maxima next to each other. However, the maxima of my function are rather spread. Using a local search algorithm with selected starting points and taking the best maximum of all found values is very likely to give the optimal result.